# facebook article:publisher does not display like button on share

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook has announced a new open graph tag recently:

```html
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/cnn" />
```

Which is intended to show a like button on shares.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/19/platform-updates--new-open-graph-tags-for-media-publishers-and-more/

We've added the tag to a page with other OG tags including the following:

```html
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

But when we share the page on Facebook, and a friend views post from another account, they do not see the 'like' button on the share post?

Are we missing something here?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  Is your issue resolved?  I also get no errors in the Facebook OG Object debugger.